# php: iterate through function arguments by key value

Tags: php, function, parameters

I have a php function `function foo($bar1, $bar2, $bar3)`

Is there a possibility to get the parameter **names and values** dynamically?

I found `func_get_args` (http://php.net/manual/de/function.func-get-args.php) but that will return something like

```
0 => "valueOf$bar1", 1=> "valueOf$bar2", 2 => "valueOf$bar3"
```

What I want instead is something like:

```
"$bar1" => "valueOf$bar1", "$bar2"=> "valueOf$bar2", "$bar3" => "valueOf$bar3"
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Short answer: no. If you want to pass key/value pairs, use an array or an object. Long(er) answer: Yes it is possible using reflection or `get_defined_vars()` and stripping out all the superglobals - but **don't**.

Comment: ... and is pointless. Function parameter names are irrelevant to PHP (still).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`get_defined_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php).  An [example](http://codepad.org/ISBY4oxy)

Comment: Hadn't thought of that, but this means you get all defined parameters, not just the actual arguments that were passed, i.e. you will have the default values of omitted parameters in the resulting array.

Comment: @soulmerge As long as you give all arguments a default of `NULL`, this shouldn't matter as `isset()` will still return `FALSE`. You could always `array_filter()` if you want to strip them completely.

Answer (score 2):

It *can* be achieved, but involves a lot of effort. You would need to get the parameter names via [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php) and map the names to the values retrieved via [`func_get_args`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php).

If you *really* need this, you can take another, simpler route and define that your function takes a single [parameter object](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ParameterObject):

```
class MyParamObj {
    public $foo;
    public $bar;
}

function myfunc(MyParamObj $args) {
    # ...
}
```

Comment: this is a good answer that would work. @Shatki Singh's answer was more what I was looking for though