# strip slahes from all arguments of a php function

Tags: php

I have these kind of php function

```
function insertData($username,$name,$password) {
}
```

and some others such as:

```
function updateData($color, $hair,$eye) {
}
```

etc..

as these arguments can contain some quotes or double quotes like " or '

Is there a way to sanitize them all like

sanitize(allFunctionargs)

without having to write
sanitize ($color);
sanitize ($hair);
sanitize ($eye);

**I am looking for the most generic function to sanitize (strip slashes) ALL arguments of a function**

Regards

Comment: Just look up prepared statements and you won't have to bother about quotes or double quotes in variables anymore. Also have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685761/php-iterate-through-function-arguments-by-key-value) if you insist on doing that.

Comment: You could use a combination of `stripslashes` and `func_get_args`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with these arguments? There may be a better way to do it.  Please show some more logic

Comment: Just read you want to strip slashes, wouldn't you want to add slashes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [func_get_args:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) and a foreach

```
function insertData($username,$name,$password) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach ($args as $arg)
    {
        // sanitize and whatnot
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Your Answer...

You cannot just call a function outside a function to sanitize all functions arguments. You will have to do this within the function like so:

```
function foo(/* Polymorphic */){

    // Sanitize the arguments
    $arguments = sanitize(function_get_args());

    // Proceed with the rest of the function
    // $arguments will now be sanitized
}

function sanitize(/* Polymorphic */){

    // Get the functions arguments
    $arguments = function_get_args();

    // If the arguments exist then proceed to sanitizing
    if(is_array($arguments)){
        foreach($arguments as $key=>$value){
            $arguments[$key] = stripslashes($value);
        }
    }

    // Return the sanitized array
    return $arguments;
}
```

*Notice the `/* Polymorphic */` comment; this effectively means that you can submit any number of arguments. The only issue here is that you do not know which arguments are which unless you submit them like so:*

```
// Call the foo function
foo(array(
    'username' => $username,
    'name'     => $name,
    'password' => $password
));
```

Then in the foo function you will be able to access the arguments like so:

```
function foo(/* Polymorphic */){

    // Sanitize the arguments
    $arguments = sanitize(function_get_args());

    // You only want the first item in the arguments array so remove the others...
    $arguments = $arguments[0];

    // Proceed with the rest of the function
    echo 'Username: '.$arguments['username']."\n";
    echo 'Name: '.$arguments['name']."\n";
    echo 'Password: '.$arguments['password'];

}
```

### However...

***If you are stripping the slashes for MySQL (or any other db) purposes, then I would hugely advise that you look at either the MySQLi or PDO libraries and prepared statements. You will not need to go to this effort of stripping the slashes if you use prepared statements. See the following link for more information:***

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function stripslashes_deep($value)
{
    $value = is_array($value) ?
                array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
                stripslashes($value);

    return $value;
}


$array = func_get_args();
$array = stripslashes_deep($array);

print_r($array);
```